# MySQL on remote box & Microsoft Entity Framework tips?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

We have a client with a MySQL database that we need to access over the internet.  A port number is open on their end for us to gain access and run queries.

I was wondering if anyone's had experience using the Entity Framework with a MySQL database over the internet and what gotchas and tips you had to share?  Is it pretty straightforward getting to the data in your experience?  We'll likely be using the most recent version of EF, if that makes a difference.  Thanks much for sharing.

Comment: This is a great question to be marked as Community Wiki. There's no real acceptable answer to this one!

Answer (score 1):

Just mentioned this over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137605/a-good-way-to-send-the-results-from-a-mysql-query-over-a-web-service/4137739#4137739)

would this be of interest [WCF Data Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WCF_Data_Services)