# A good way to send the results from a MySQL query over a Web Service?

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services

I've been trying to figure out a good and easy way to send the results of a MySQL Query over my Web Service.

There is a lot of good methods that I've looked into, like Data Transfer Object, but I would like to keep it as simple as possible. At this point simply getting this to work has a higher priority. :)

Any help or documentation is welcome, even on more difficult topics, but as mentioned above the simpler the better at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you say expose your results, do you also mean dynamic querying? such as [Wcf Data Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WCF_Data_Services)

However be careful on what and how you expose information. It is a pain to go back and fix it.

for SOA or a 3 physical Tier I would consider using

- Service Layer
- Data transfer objects, they are great, exposing data directly can cause issues with maintainability/Changeability

to help with DTO's look at AutoMapper, it was designed for it.

if I have missed a point, add a comment

ps here is a great list of helpful patterns [PoEAA Catalogue](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)

Comment: I love you dude! AutoMapper is just amazing!<3